# angular 2 - When i make a router navigate, the resolver react before the OnDestroy on the current page

Tags: angular, components, router, ondestroy, resolver

I have two route:

```
{path: 'route1',component: component1,resolve: {parameters: resolver1}}
{path: 'route2',component: component2,resolve: {parameters: resolver2}}
```

I navigate from route1  to route2 , the route2's resolver react before `Ondestroy` route1 , is it logical ?

My issue is that, if I call a service on resolver2 which update an object1 bound with an observable on the page1 all observable's object1 on this page1 will react .

I find that weird because we leave the page . Furthermore , if requests of service are present in the Observable they also react and so we have too much request's service  .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is completely logical. What is a resolver? It is a piece of code that makes sure that some initial data is loaded **before** a route is initialized and the component is loaded, so, for example, a user is not presented with a blank page if data load fails and **remains** on the previous page. You can think of it like this: when you start navigation, if there are any resolvers, they will run, and if (and only if) the data is successfully loaded, the previous component will be destroyed (thus invoking `ngOnDestroy`) and replaced with a new one, so yes, this is not only completely logical, but actually the only proper way to implement such behavior.
You can read more about resolvers [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)

Comment: ok  i understand the behaviour  and  thank's for explanations . i will try to find an another way to call just one times my observables on the current page , may be do you have any idea for this ?

Comment: If you provide some insight into your actual code, I may be able to help